# Sharing instances and methods/variables within a form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, instance

I'm very new to c# and just started to use forms to create a GUI.

Here's some code:

```
    public void Server_connect_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open CasparCG server connection and create a TCP client
        int port = portnumber;
        TcpClient serv1 = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
    }

    public void Disconnect_server_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serv1.Close();
    }
```

This is code from a couple of button implementations within Form1.cs.

The problem I have is that the serv1 instance in the Disconnect_server button code is not recognised. So the instance is not making it's way out of the Server_connect code. I've tried using the same code (as well as variables and methods) within the Main() code in Program.cs but I'm unable to get any recognition of any of these outside of the same block of code into the button code so I'm clearly overlooking something. I've tried making everything public etc. but it all seems to make no difference. Nothing seems to communicate variables/methods/instances anywhere else in the code.

Please realise I'm a beginner with this language so I'm sometimes getting stuck on this (presumably) basic stuff.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Issue is Variable Scoping , right now variable scope is upto the method `Server_connect_button_Click`, you need to increate scope of variable at class level

For providing instance to all you method in given class you can do like this

```
class Abc {
  private TcpClient serv1;

  public void Server_connect_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Open CasparCG server connection and create a TCP client
    int port = portnumber;
    serv1 = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
  }

  public void Disconnect_server_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(serv1!=null)
     serv1.Close();
  }
}
```

What I mean to say is you need to declare variable at class level to resolve your issue, the current problem with your code is scope of a variable is up to given method only